# If $0<t<1$ then $0<t^n<1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis

Let $(F, +, \cdot, -,^{-1},0,1,<)$ be an ordered field, that is:

There exists a binary operation $+$ on $F$ such that

- $\forall x, y\in F, x+y\in F$
- $\forall x,y\in F, x+(y+x)=(x+y)+x$
- $\forall x\in F, \forall y\in F, x+y=y+x$
- $\exists 0\in F: \forall x\in F, x+0=x$
- $\forall x\in F, \exists -x\in F: x+(-x)=0$

There is a binary operation $\cdot$ on $F$ such that:

- $\forall x,y\in F, x\cdot y\in F$
- $\forall x,y\in F, x\cdot y=y\cdot x$
- $\forall x,y\in F, x\cdot (y\cdot z)=(x\cdot y)\cdot z$
- $\exists 1\in F,:\forall x\in F, x\cdot 1=x$
- $\forall x\in F\exists x^{-1}\in F: x\cdot x^{-1}=1$
- $\forall x,y,z\in F, x\cdot (y+z)=x\cdot y+x\cdot z$

Let $<$ be a total and transitive order on $F$, such that

- if $x,y,z\in F$ and $y<z$ then $x+y<x+z$
- if $x,y\in F$, $x>0$ and $y>0$ then $xy>0$

Is it possible to prove that, for every $t\in F$, if $0<t<1$ then $t^n<1$ for every integer $n>1$?

EDIT: if necessary, suppose that $F$ has the least-upper-bound property.

Comment: Prove that if $0<x<a$ and $0<y<b$, then $0<xy<ab$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is
\begin{gather}
1-t > 0 \Rightarrow t(1-t)>0 \Rightarrow t>t^2
\end{gather}
And in the same way:
$$
t^i>t^{i+1}, \quad \forall i=0,1,...
$$
Hence you have:
$$
1>t>t^2>\cdots >t^n
$$

Answer (score 2):

You can prove that by induction:

First observe that, because of $t>o$, you have $t^2=t \cdot t>0$, and so on $t^n>0$ for every $n \ge 1$.

Now, the base case n=1 is trivially satysfied;

Assume that if $0<t<1$ then $0<t^k<1$, therefore: 
$$0<t^k<1 \; \Longrightarrow \; 0=t^k-t^k<1-t^k \; \Longrightarrow \; 0<t(1-t^k)=t-t^{k+1} \; \Longrightarrow \; t^{k+1}<t<1$$
So for the first observation and for this last result we have $0<t^{k+1}<1$, which completes the induction step.